# How to return an array in one line in Java?

Tags: java, memory-management

What happens to memory when this code is executed?

```
int[] dim1 = new int[2];
dim1 = myObject.getCoord();

public int[] getCoord() {
   int[] dim2 = new int[] {y1, x1} ;
    return dim2;
}
```

It seems that the space is first allocated for two arrays `dim1` and `dim2`. While dim1 will live, dim2 lives for just two lines and then goes to gc. It seems to cause some performance issues with really large arrays. Yet, code below is a compile time error.

```
public int[] getCoord() {
    return {y1, x1} ;
}
```

What is the logic behind? What is the correct way to create just one array?

Comment: "While dim1 will live, dim2 lives for just two lines and then goes to gc." This is not true. It depends on what you do with the returned array. If the result (aka. the reference address of the new array in the method) is stored in some reference (as you do in your example), it will not be garbage-collected.

Comment: well, the *initial value* of dim1 only lives for one line, and then immediately gets replaced by the result of calling getCoord.  that "dim2" (now assigned to dim1) reference lives as long s dim1 is referenced by something.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

do you mean like this?

```
int[] dim1 = myObject.getCoord();

public int[] getCoord() {
    return new int[] {y1, x1} ;
}
```

only one array is ever created, by the method call, and only has one reference, dim1.

but *ideally* you probably don't want a "get" method to be creating new things, as just by looking at the declaration you might not expect that.  personally, i'd prefer

```
int[] dim1 = myObject.createCoord();

public int[] createCoord() {
    return new int[] {y1, x1} ;
}
```

which makes it explicit that the method is "creating" a thing.

Comment: `get…` methods which create an object are pretty much standard for all properties of a mutable object type. It would be rather surprising if they return a reference to the internal mutable state. Besides that, the object creation is irrelevant for the program’s logic, so why bother emphasizing it in the method’s name.

Comment: because if the object it returns is *also* mutable, like the point, you might assume that  if you do `point p1 = x.getCoord(); p1.x = 100; point p2 = x.getCoord();` that `p2.x == p1.x`, which is definitely not true if you do something like above.  if the method was called createCoord, then you'd have a better idea that calling it subsequent times isn't going to give you the same object.

Comment: What you describe, is what I described as “return a reference to the internal mutable state” which is not the norm. Look at all JRE getter methods returning a mutable object. Unless explicitly stated otherwise, they all return a new object. As I said, being able to actually change the property via `object.getCoord().x = newValue;` would be the surprising behavior.

Comment: yes, if something is immutable, it shouldn't be returning something internal that is mutable, like an array, in the first place. my answer was *specific* to this *specific case*, where it is returning a new array, which by definition itself is mutable.  if it was `ImmutableArray<int> getCoord()` sure, but is returning a new array every time you call it, hence my suggestion that `get` was not very descriptive, *in this specific case*

Comment: Apparently, you misunderstood. See for example AWT `Component.getForeground()`, `Component.getFont()` or `Component.getName()`. Since `Color`, `Font` and `String` are immutable, a direct reference is returned. In contrast, `Component.getLocation()`, `Component.getSize()` and `Component.getBounds()` return copies, because `Point`, `Dimension` and `Rectangle` are mutable. The general design pattern is that you are **not** capable of modifying the property via the object returned by a `get…` method. No-one should be surprised by that; it’s the way it works since Java 1.1.

Answer (score 0):

When you reassign `dim1`, it forgets the previous value it stored. It's actually the initial (empty) value of `dim1` which is getting garbage collected. You could just as easily have done:

```
int[] dim1 = new int[0];
```

In order to save memory.

For a one-liner, just do:

```
int[] dim1 = myObject.getCoord();
```

And then in your method use:

```
return new int[] { y1, x1 };
```

However, this will consume the exact same amount of memory as my first option.

Comment: To be clear, your first option allocates memory for a zero-element array: the array itself doesn't take up any memory, but the reference does, and that is subject to garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

No matter how you try to shorten your code, it doesn't change the fact that when the call to `getCoord()` returns, it simply returns a ***reference*** to the array, not a ***copy of the contents*** of the array.

Trying to make the code more succinct won't help you with your performance problem.

Just don't initialize `dim1` to `new int[2];` at the beginning if you want, because it gets replaced right after anyways. But that's small potatoes.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you could ensure only one array is created.

```
int[] dim = myObject.getCoord();
```

Or

```
int[] coord = new int[2];
myObject.setCoord(coord);

public void setCoord(int[] coord) {
    coord[0] = x;
    coord[1] = y;
}
```